# No suitable driver found for jdbc - Oracle, while connecting with Kafka Connect

Tags: oracle, jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, ojdbc

I am trying to run an oracle source connector in Kafka using Oracle jdbc8 (ojdbc8.jar) in standalone mode. I have downloaded the confluent's jdbc jars and also the ojdbc8.jar from the Oracle website. I have tested this locally and it worked fine, but on our test environment, it is throwing the following error:

```
No suitable driver found for jdbc:oracle:thin:@x.x.x.x:yyyy:zzz for configuration Couldn't open connection to jdbc:oracle:thin:@x.x.x.x:yyyy:zzz
```

Full error message:

```
ERROR Failed to create job for xyz/xyz.properties (org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone:110)
[2020-03-11 13:13:32,085] ERROR Stopping after connector error (org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone:121)
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.errors.BadRequestException: Connector configuration is invalid and contains the following 2 error(s):
Invalid value java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:oracle:thin:@x.x.x.x:1521:xyz for configuration Couldn't open connection to jdbc:oracle:thin:@x.x.x.x:1521:xyz
Invalid value java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:oracle:thin:@x.x.x.x:1521:xyz for configuration Couldn't open connection to jdbc:oracle:thin:@x.x.x.x:1521:xyz
```

Plugins' path is also fine as it is registering all the jars. I have tried some fixes I found online which included putting the plugins path in the CLASSPATH variable. It didn't work, threw the same error as aforementioned. I am also able to ping and telnet the IP and Port respectively.

My connector configurations are as follows:

```
name=oracle-jdbc-connect
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector
tasks.max=1
connection.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@x.x.x.x:yyyy:zzz
connection.user=xyz
connection.password=xyz
query=SELECT cast(ID AS NUMBER(7, 0)) AS ID, NAME FROM sch.tbl
mode=incrementing
incrementing.column.name=ID
topic.prefix=topic-test
schema.pattern=sch
numeric.mapping=best_fit
dialect.name=OracleDatabaseDialect
timestamp.delay.interval.ms=5000
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
key.converter.schemas.enable=false
value.converter.schemas.enable=false
decimal.handling.mode=double
include.schema.changes=false
```

The connection.user given here has 'read-only' privileges in Oracle though. Can that be an issue here?
connect-standalone.properties file is as follows:

```
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
key.converter.schemas.enable=true
value.converter.schemas.enable=true
offset.storage.file.filename=/tmp/connect.offsets
offset.flush.interval.ms=10000
rest.host.name=x.x.x.x
rest.port=8877 # Some random port
plugin.path=/home/plugins/,/usr/share/java,/usr/local/share/kafka/plugins
```

**Oracle Version:** 18c
**Kafka Version:** 2.3.0
**Scala Version:** 2.12.2

**plugins.path:** /home/plugins

**Plugins Path Structure**: /home/plugins/connectors/ [Folders like assets, docs, lib etc.], ojdbc8.jar.

Inside /home/plugins/connectors/lib, I have kafka-connect-jdbc-5.4.0.jar file.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include a complete folder listing of where you have your JDBC driver and Kafka Connect JDBC JARs?

Comment: and have you reviewed https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-connect-deep-dive-jdbc-source-connector/ ?

Comment: @RobinMoffatt, edited at the end. Please, check! And yes, I have read that blogpost.

Comment: Can you post the *full* error? What comes after `Couldn't open connection to jdbc:oracle:thin:@x.x.x.x:yyyy:zzz` ?

Comment: @RobinMoffatt, edited the question. Included the full error.

Comment: Does it work if you use this same setup against the Oracle DB that works in your local system? And visa versa - if you use your local system to connect to the Oracle DB in this test system?

Comment: In the blog, shows editing the log level to inspect whether drivers are discovered. Please edit your question to include that step

Comment: @CyberKnight, were you able to find the solution?

Answer (score 2):

Your `ojdbc8.jar` needs to be *in the same folder* as the Kafka Connect JDBC JAR.

So if Kafka Connect JDBC JAR is in `/home/plugins/connectors/lib` then put `ojdbc8.jar` in there too.

Comment: I tried that initially. Didn't work and gave the same error. After reading your answer, I tried it again. But still the same error.

Comment: The structure I provided in my answer above is the same as my local system and it is working fine there.

Comment: worked for me, I was using a different folder for my plugins which I added to plugin path. jdbc folder was there and I moved it to `/kafka/confluent-7.0.1/share/java/ folder`. it seems working now!

Answer (score 1):

update to ojdbc10 if you are using java11. For kafka ojdbc8 is compatible with java8 and ojdbc10 with java11.

Comment: ojdbc8.jar can also be used with JDK11. Check out the FAQ (https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/faq-jdbc.html)
ojdbc10.jar with JDK10, JDK11
ojdbc8.jar with JDK8, JDK9, JDK11